# Extending Selenium via –userExtensions argument not working from an ant target ? Need Help?

Tags: selenium

To be very short and specific , I'm launching the "Selenium Server" from an ant task of my  project "build.xml" as follows : -

```
<target name="startServer">
  <java jar="${basedir}/lib/selenium-server.jar" fork="true" spawn="true">        
    <arg value="-userExtensions"/>
    <arg value="${basedir}/lib/user-extensions.js"/>
  </java>
</target>
```

Where as, below is the simple code chunk for my "user-extensions.js" file

Selenium.prototype.doMyMethod = function(locator) {
     var element = this.page().findElement(locator);
     element.click();
   };

However, when i call this method in my "java driven test case" as follows , it's not working at all :-

Controller.commandProcessor.doCommand("myMethod",new String[] {"btnG"}); 
   //user extension

Where, "commandProcessor" being an instance of "HttpCommandProcessor" as follows and being accessible as public static property within another custom coded java file "Controller" :-

public static HttpCommandProcessor commandProcessor;
commandProcessor = new HttpCommandProcessor('localhost', 4444, '*firefox', 'http://www.google.com/');

Moreover, other built-in function calls like "type, getTitle" are working correctly, but this extension part not working properly and giving an error on this line as : -

ERROR: Unknown command: 'myMethod'

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Unknown command: 'myMethod'

Which is clearly an evidence that "user-extension.js" was not added actually !

Is there a way to work around this particular problem when launching selenium from an ant target as above !

Any quick help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Magically, i got it working, i guess some network problem (internet connectivity) at my end was causing it to fail, I'm not sure upon it, but now it's working perfectly fine. In short, that "user-extension.js" should be in the same directory, where your "**selenium-server.jar**" is located, and the above way of passing "**-userExtensions**" via "**ant target**" is the right perfect way :) !